# Looping through two JSON arrays Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get data from a Json file using the id from a previous previous ajax call looping through the the second array based on the `id` gotten from the first

I have tried

```
    $(document).on('click', '.stories', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=front_title',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
        });


         request.done(function (output) {

        if (output.result === 'success') {     
       var n = output.data[0].title_count;
            $('.blog').empty();
       for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
            var storytitle = output.data[i].story_view;
            var id = output.data[i].titleID;


            var request2 = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=story_episodes',
            cache: false,
            data: 'id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
            });

            request2.done(function (output2) {

            if (output2.result === 'success') {     
            var n2 = output2.data[0].episode_count;
            for (var i=0; i<n2; i++) {
                var titles =  output2.data[i].title;
                console.log(storytitle + " " + titles);
            }
        }


        else {
                console.log('faileds');
            }

        });

   }

   } else {
                console.log('failed');
            }

        });
});
```

The `storyTitle` has a single value and loops through all the titles when i check my console.
I tried debugging and found out the second for-loop was only executed once, after executing request2.done, it goes back to the first for-loop after the first has finish all its loop, it executes the second for-loop.
I don't know where am missing it.I need help with this.

Comment: how many times is request2.done getting called?

Comment: It was called once...

Comment: You need to format this code better.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem...Changed my code to...

```
    $(document).on('click', '.stories', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=front_title',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
        });


         request.done(function (output) {

        if (output.result === 'success') {     
       var n = output.data[0].title_count;
            var jsonArray = $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(output.data))).each(function() {  
         var id = this.titleID;
         var CLASS = this.story_view;


            var request2 = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=story_episodes',
            cache: false,
            data: 'id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
            });

            request2.done(function (output2) {

            if (output2.result === 'success') {
                var jsonArray2 = $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(output2.data))).each(function() {  
                var id2 = this.id;
                console.log(id + " " + id2);

            })
        }
        })

   })
   } else {
                console.log('failed');
            }

        });
})
```

And it worked fine....thanks to [Swapnil Godambe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230359/swapnil-godambe)